# jquery autocomplete not display under input text box it display on top left corner but correct under input?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I work on asp.net mvc autocomplete . I face issue autocomplete display success list but it display on wrong place .

so How to solve this issue please

Exactly I need auto complete display under input textbox ?

I display employee name  on control id `LineManagerName` based on selection changed from autocomplete for employee id that represent control id `txtLineManagerId`

correct behaviour that auto complete display under input text box `txtLineManagerId`

What I try

```js
//--work success----

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtLineManagerId").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      var searchText = $("#txtLineManagerId").val();
      console.log("search text" + searchText)
      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEmployeeBasedSearchText", "Resignation")',
        data: {
          searchText: searchText
        },
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          /* console.log("data is " + data);*/
          response($.map(data, function(item) {
            console.log("data is" + item.EmployeeID);
            return {
              label: item.EmployeeID,
              value: item.EmployeeID,
              employeeName: item.EmployeeName
            };
          }))
        }
      });
    },
    position: {
      my: "right top",
      at: "right bottom"
    },
    appendTo: '#searchContainer',
    select: function(event, ui) {

      $("#LineManagerName").val(ui.item.employeeName);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 hover">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LineManager, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
      <span class="text-danger"> *</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LineManager, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtLineManagerId" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LineManager, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 hover">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DirectManager, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
      <span class="text-danger"> *</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 hover">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      @Html.Label("Line Manager Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
      <span class="text-danger"> *</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <input type="text" id="LineManagerName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="searchContainer">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

issue image
[image: autocomplete display on wrong place]

**Updated post**

can you tell me how to add position relative or absolute on answer please so i will test it

so how to clean up jQuery version can you please tell me what I do

to clean up jQuery version

what scripts CSS and bootstrap and JavaScript and jQuery required for

working autocomplete .

Only Need suitable scripts CSS and jQuery and bootstrap suitable for my case

Comment: position: relative or absolute need to be there

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: can you tell me how to add position relative i will test but tell me how to make position relative

Comment: First thing I would advise is not to use multiple versions of jQuery or jQuery UI. You have multiple versions of both. This needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: Second, your example code references elements that do not appear in the HTML. E.G.: `$("#txtLineManagerId")`

Comment: so how to clean up jquery version can you please tell me what i do